# nushell - how to list aliases?

Tags: alias, nushell

The [official docs](https://www.nushell.sh/book/aliases.html) of nushell claim that one is able to list available aliases via:

```
$nu.scope.aliases
```

However this does not work on my Arch Linux machine:

```
/home/rne〉pacman -Q nushell                                                                                                                                               2023-08-15 20:04:36
nushell 0.83.1-1
/home/rne〉$nu.scope.aliases                                                                                                                                               2023-08-15 20:04:39
Error: nu::shell::column_not_found

  × Cannot find column
   ╭─[entry #13:1:1]
 1 │ $nu.scope.aliases
   · ─┬─ ──┬──
   ·  │    ╰── cannot find column 'scope'
   ·  ╰── value originates here
   ╰────

/home/rne〉echo $nu.scope.aliases                                                                                                                                          2023-08-15 20:04:42
Error: nu::shell::column_not_found

  × Cannot find column
   ╭─[entry #14:1:1]
 1 │ echo $nu.scope.aliases
   ·      ─┬─ ──┬──
   ·       │    ╰── cannot find column 'scope'
   ·       ╰── value originates here
   ╰────

/home/rne〉                                                                                                                                                                2023-08-15 20:04:44
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation appears to be outdated.
You can list aliases with the undocumented

```
help aliases
```

and

```
scope aliases
```

commands.

See also: https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/9011#issuecomment-1679486217
and: https://github.com/nushell/nushell.github.io/pull/1006

Outdated docs have been updated with my PR linked above.